# How to use a list of objects or array in json post request to a WebService?

Tags: json, web-services, list, post

as described in the title, I'm trying to call a WebService method via JSON/Ajax in JavaScript with several String parameters and 2 lists or arrays.

For now everything worked fine with single parameters in this format:

`var WSParameters = "{pParam1: 'abc', pParam2: 'def'}"`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/" + webMethod,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: WSParameters,
        success: function (result) {
            // stuff to be done on if request was successful
        },
        error: function (message) { alert('Error loading data! ' + message.responseText); }
    });
```

But now I need to provide the web service method a list/array of values. The web service method looks like this:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public void editExistingSystem(System.Collections.Generic.List<String> pFirstList,
        System.Collections.Generic.List<String> pSecondList, 
        String pParam1,
        String pParam2)
    {
      // Stuff
    }
```

I guess it should be something like this, but obviously this didn't work:

`var WSParameters = "{pFirstList: 15,4,13, pSecondList: 'gr00001_96594737', pParam1: 'abc', pParam2: 'def'}"`

Could you please help me with finding the correct syntax to define a list in this parameter list?

Thanks a lot in davance

Br
vm370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often, I found the solution almost right after asking the question...
Sorry guys for bothering you. The correct paramter string to the example in my starting post would be:

```
var WSParameters = "{pfirstList: ['15','4','13'], pSecondList: ['gr00001_96594737'], pParam1: 'abc', pParam2: 'def'}"
```

Thanks and best regards
vm370

Comment: Always validate your JSON using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or similar tools